# find $f^n $ in terms of $a, b, x, n,$ from $ f(x) = ax + b, -1<a<1, f^n(x) = f(f^{n-1}(x)), (n = 2,3,4,...) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> find $f^n,$ in terms of $a, b, x, n,$ from $ f(x) = ax + b, -1<a<1, f^n(x) = f(f^{n-1}(x)), (n = 2,3,4,...) $

$f^2(x) = f(f(x)) = a(ax + b) + b$

$f^3(x) = f(f^2(x)) = a(a(ax + b) + b) + b$

can someone help me please?

Comment: Suppose $f^n(x)=a_nx+b_n$. What can you conclude about $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: $a^n x$ and $b$ still the same..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing a few terms:

$$f(x) = ax+b = a^1x + b(1)\\ f^2(x) = f(f(x)) = a(ax+b) +b = a^2x+ab +b = a^2x + b(1+a)\\ f^3(x) = f(f(f(x))) = a(a^2x+ab+b)+b = a^3x+a^2b+ab+b = a^3x + b(1+a+a^2)$$
$$\vdots $$

> $$f^n(x) = a^nx + b(1+a+a^2+\cdots a^{n-1}) = a^nx+b\frac{a^{n}-1}{a-1}$$

Comment: why... it's so easy for you... thank you...

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: but, i still not understand why it turn's out like that... can you clarify it?

Comment: The terms with b form a geometric progression and it's just the sum of the geometric series

Comment: $Sn = a(1-r^n)/(1-r)$ when is this applied? Why yours is , $Sn = a(r^n-1)/(r-1)$

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator by - 1. Both are the same

Answer (score 1):

If I expand the product of $f^3(x)$, I obtain: $f^3(x)=a^3x+a^2b+ab^1+ab^0$. Now I pick up $b$: $f^3(x)=a^3x+b(a^2+a^1+a^0)$ which is a geometric progression of reason $a$ and the sum is $b\frac{a^3-1}{a-1}$. In general I have $n$ terms: $b(a^n+a^{n-1}\cdot\cdot\cdot +a^0)$ and their sum is: $b\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$. Now I have to sum $a^nx$.

Comment: ok, thank you...